# Number of days left in current month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Number of days left in a given month
How do I find the number of days left in the current month?
Example if current month is November and todays date is 16/11/2016 
The Numbers of days in month – Elapse days = ? I want to do it dynamically
In my example  30 – 16 = 14

```
declare @date date 
set @date='16 Nov 2016'
select datediff(day, @date, dateadd(month, 1, @date)) - 16 AS DaysLeft
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the Datepart function:

```
declare @date date
set @date='16 Nov 2016'
select datediff(day, @date, dateadd(month, 1, @date)) - Datepart(DAY,@date)
```

Answer (score 6):

Since this is sql server 2008 you can't use EOMonth (that was introduced in 2012 version).
You have to do some date adds and date diffs:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, 
                GETDATE(),
                DATEADD(MONTH, 
                        1, 
                        DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()) 
                       ) 
               ) - 1
```

explanations:
`DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE())` gets the first day of the current month, the wrapping `DATEADD` adds one month, and the wrapping `DATEDIFF` returns the number of days between the current date and the first date of the next month. This is why you need to subtruct 1 to get the correct number of days.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 2):

```
--For SQL 2012 And Above Version Use Below Query to Get Count Of Days Left In A Month

DECLARE @date DATE
SET @date=GETDATE()
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @date,EOMONTH(@date)) 

-- And for Sql Server 2008 Use Below Query to Get Count of Days Left for the Month
    DECLARE @date Date 
         SET @date=GETDATE()
         SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @date, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @date)) - DATENAME(DAY,GETDATE())
     AS DaysLeft
```

Comment: that's a 2012 feature i believe

Comment: Yes That's a 2012 And Above SQL Server Version Feature

Comment: question tagged 2008

Comment: ohhh yeah I didn't concentrate on 2008 Instead I Just Concentrate on SQL Server

Comment: So I Make The Change for 2008 Version

Comment: That's some fine work of noticing, Mr. @Tanner :) Also Alfaiz Ahmed, seeing the answer is valid (after updating), its currently flagged as low-quality due to the length, not adding any context to the answer. Perhaps add the previous code to versions higher then 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Change your date to getdate()

```
     declare @date date 
     set @date=GETDATE()
     select datediff(day, @date, dateadd(month, 1, @date)) - DATENAME(DAY,GETDATE())
 AS DaysLeft
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @date DATE SET @date='16 Nov 2016' SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @date,EOMONTH(@date))
```

Comment: that's a 2012 feature i believe

Answer (score 1):

Use `EOMONTH` and `DATEDIFF` functions

```
    declare @date date 
    set @date='16 Nov 2016'
    select datediff(day,@date,eomonth(@date)) as days_left
```

Use below solution For Below versions of `sql server 2012`

```
    DECLARE @DATE DATE 
    SET @DATE='16 NOV 2016'
    SELECT   DATEDIFF(DAY,@DATE,DATEADD( MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,@DATE)+1,0))-1 AS DAYS_LEFT
```

Comment: that's a 2012 feature i believe

Answer (score 0):

FUNCTION example

```
CREATE Or ALTER FUNCTION ReturnDaysLeftInMonth(@Date Date)
RETURNS Int
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN DATEDIFF(DAY, @Date, EOMONTH(@Date)) + 1
END
```

Or use

```
Declare @Date Date 
Set @Date=GETDATE()
DATEDIFF(DAY, @Date, EOMONTH(@Date)) + 1
```