# calculate how many days were left by the end of the month based on current date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to calculate how many days were left by the end of the month based on current date

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ?

Comment: Take the last day of the month and subtract the current day. Details on how to do that highly depend on the DBMS used.

Comment: i am using in Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: I downvoted because no effort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of days left in current month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40631064/number-of-days-left-in-current-month)    Funny how I was able to throw the exact question posed above into Google and found this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE() , EOMONTH(GETDATE())) AS days;
```

`GETDATE()` returns the current date.

`EOMONTH(..)` returns the last date in the current month.